# Android - open image from drawable in default gallery application

Tags: java, android

I'm working on app that have number of imageviews,
when i click on the image i want it to open via android default gallery image picker.
i've tried in this way :

```
String str = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.drawable.wall1;

Uri path = Uri.parse(str);
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

but it doesn't work and i get exception:
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.example.demo/2130837505 typ=image/* }

Comment: You might want to write the drawable to a temp sdcard location instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because there is no activity on your device capable of viewing an image residing at a `Uri` with the `android:resource://` scheme. If I had to guess, ~99% of Android devices will have a similar problem.

Either write your own image viewer, or move the image someplace that third-party apps are more likely to support, such as your own `ContentProvider` or a local file.