# Opening an image from drawable in gallery viewer?

Tags: android, uri, android-gallery, android-drawable

I found some solutions for this, but none of them seemed to work for me.

I want to open an image I have from the drawable folder in the android gallery, without copying it to the SD card.

I don't know much about the URI either, is it just the package name?

Comment: Go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525316/android-open-image-from-drawable-in-default-gallery-application?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525316/android-open-image-from-drawable-in-default-gallery-application?rq=1)

Comment: Ok, but how would I do what it says on there?

Comment: Post something your work around..